# Microsoft Edge Driver (Incorrect XPath behavior for partial @class matches)

Tags: webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

Windows 10
Microsoft Edge Version 40.15063.674.0 (15.15063)

An XPath that works fine in Chrome and Firefox is failing in Microsoft Edge.

var filterRow2 = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table//tr[contains(@class,'table-filter')]"));

this find the element when run in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge. I found posts in the microsoft developer forum discussing the same issue but didn't see anything stating the issue was ever resolved.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4696709/
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8516233/

---

More Information:

Example code which fails in version 15063
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your 1 line of code with Edge web driver and chrome web driver. (Tested with Edge 44)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
             // IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

                String xpath = "//body[contains(@class, 'home-page new-topbar')]";

                var filterRow2 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table//tr[contains(@class,'table-filter')]"));

                Console.WriteLine(filterRow2.ToString());

                driver.Close();

}
```

Below is the result from Chrome Web driver.

[image]

Below is the result from Edge Web driver.

[image]

I suggest you to use the latest updates for MS Edge browser and use latest web driver for Edge may help to fix the issue.

Reference:

[Microsoft Edge (Incorrect XPath behavior for partial @class matches)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/63e99b00-109b-489a-913a-82a11c9980ba/microsoft-edge-incorrect-xpath-behavior-for-partial-class-matches?forum=iewebdevelopment)

Let us know, if I misunderstand anything from your above description. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: Hi Deepak, in the example above, you don't actually test to see if it will find if the contains finds what you are looking for. It is correct that the statement, var filterRow2 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table//tr[contains(@class,'table-filter')]"));, will not fail. However, it will return 0 elements. FindElements doesn't if there are no matches (like FindElement) it just returns 0 elements. Have you tried the Xpath on an actual table?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm in the process of getting the latest version of Edge